# How can I resize my uploaded images?

Tags: php

```
<?php
require_once ('../index.php'); 
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/>";
}
else
{   
}
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        if (file_exists("../uploadedImages/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "../uploadedImages/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Du har laddat upp en bild.";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

---

I wanna be able to resize my image, when i upload my image.
The code that I have now Im uploading a image to my uploadedImages folder, and I want to resize my images to small thumbs.

Comment: Have you tried to google about how to resize images in php? Tiny hint: there are thousands of articles there

Comment: You ll have to copy the exciting uploaded image and then resize it. Tons of pages about it. Here is one for you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Comment: @Dorvalla Im gonna try it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script resize an Image into two 60px and 25px. Take a look at $newwidth you have to modify size values.

```
<?php 

 define ("MAX_SIZE","400");

 $errors=0;

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
        $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
 $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

  if ($image) 
  {
  $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
  $extension = strtolower($extension);
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") 
&& ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
  {
echo ' Unknown Image extension ';
$errors=1;
  }
 else
{
   $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
 echo "You have exceeded the size limit";
 $errors=1;
}

if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

$newwidth=60;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

$newwidth1=25;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,
 $width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1, 
$width,$height);

$filename = "images/". $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filename1 = "images/small". $_FILES['file']['name'];

imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
}
}
}
//If no errors registred, print the success message

 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {
   // mysql_query("update SQL statement ");
  echo "Image Uploaded Successfully!";

 }
 ?>
```

Finds file extensions.

```
function getExtension($str) {

         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; } 
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }
```

Comment: Download Full working demo : picdemo.php
http://www29.zippyshare.com/v/77682866/file.html

Comment: Im to get your code to work, but nothing its hapening, Its just a blank page now. Can you explain your code above?

Comment: have you download code  and created "images" folder when you save file ?

Comment: I have replaced images folder name with my name folder uploadedImages,but Its not working. Where should I put your function code?

Comment: Its working !! download file which I have given in link .

Comment: I downloade your file, and I made a copy & paste with your code, and I changed the folder images to mu folder name uploadedImages but its not working. Its says upload file sucessfully, but I can not finde the file.

Comment: Its 110% working ! complete your profile or add me on your gmail . I solve it !!

Comment: have you create mu folder in your file location ?

Comment: Now Its working, I made a misstake with my folder location. I just wonder one thing, Is the small images suposed to be saved in ../uploadedImages/small like this line $filename1 = "../uploadedImages/small". $_FILES['file']['name'];

Comment: I dont understand . Can you ask again please in better way ?

Comment: Im saving a small size image thumb in uploadedImages folder and Im wondering if i can save my small size images thumbs in a folder called thumbs inside my folder uploadedImages?

Comment: Create thumbs  under images folder and changes this  >> $filename1 = "images/thumbs/small". $_FILES['file']['name'];

Answer (score 1):

Google "php resize image on upload"

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Looks like something I implemented some years back, therefore I can recommend this article.

Comment: Worked perfectly when I needed it

Comment: @eXOdu5 Thanks, Im gonna check your link out.