# Image Uploader with Crop & Resize

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload

Well.. I have been looking for a image upload with a crop and resize function..

Found a lot.
But I can find one where I can choose a MUST-BE width..

So that if my MUST-BE width is set to be 250px.

Then the crop should allow a minumum width, which should be the set MUST-BE width.
It should be possible to be bigger then the MUST-BE width while cropping, but after cropping, it should resize the width to be the set MUST-BE width..

Hope I make sense.

I found this: http://www.nwhite.net/2009/02/25/lassocrop-preview/
Which do most of the magic.

I just don't know how to get PHP to do those actions after selected the right crop size?
And how to make the upload function to work with this.

Comment: What's your problem, exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891292/how-can-i-resize-my-uploaded-images/12891363#12891363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we can get x,y ,h and w. Then you can assign these values to four different hidden input fields for eg:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" id="x1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" id="y1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" id="x2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" id="y2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" id="w" />
        <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" id="h" />
```

like that and using form action you can get all values at action page \

```
$x1 = $_POST["x1"];
$y1 = $_POST["y1"];
$x2 = $_POST["x2"];
$y2 = $_POST["y2"];
$w  = $_POST["w"];
$h  = $_POST["h"];
```

Using some php image functions we can crop images

imagecreatetruecolor();

imagecopyresampled();

imagegif() or imagejpeg() or imagepng ()

I think these can already know these basic php functions and how to use it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an tutorial which does both the javascript and the PHP side of things: http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop-v11/

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/17/jquery-image-cropper-with-uploader/